# Problems using the 'Split' tool with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, algorithm

I'm running into difficulty when using the `split` tool with ArcGIS 10.

[image]

I am trying to split lines using a grid that I generated using the Fishnet command. Each gridcell has a unique text value as a name (FID converted to a string), which is my `Split Field`. However, I can't tell whether it is the size of my grid (300000 cells), or if it is due to no line being within a cell that causes the error.

[image]

I tried breaking my grid cell into smaller pieces of ~50000 cells, but I still got an error occuring. Then I tried selecting only cells that were intersected by the lines, and just splitting using those cells, and still got an error. The strange part about the error messages, were that the analysis would run for about 30 minutes or so, producing output, and then an error message would appear on screen, but no explanation - no error number or no further details.

What I have no resorted to doing is splitting the grid into 500 smaller grids, and then splitting each subgrid on itself. Then I will loop through every cell, and clip the lines to each cell. The problem with this approach is that it is taking a long time (~20 hours so far).

Are there any ways I can improve this process?

Comment: Try a few things and let us know the results: Try selecting only four cells of the grid and running your split command; then try selecting four empty cells and running it. If those both work, try progressively larger selections of cells until you get an error

Comment: There are many reasons for errors, but we can narrow them down by trying those things. Also, could you let us know the name of the actual error?

Comment: @Patrick - I'll try that. Strangely, there were no names (or numbers) with the errors. I'm using to getting ERROR: 9234XX etc; these had no identifiers.

Comment: That's really odd. Was it one of the "send feedback" errors? Or did ArcMap keep running?

Comment: No, it was just one of the pop-up 'Split Failed' errors. When I examined it in the results there were no further details, just the small red circle signifying that it had failed, but no error numbers or warnings.

Comment: Very odd. Any luck trying four (or even just one) grid cell? I'll go ahead and give an answer that avoids `Split` altogether.

Comment: No problems running the split on a few cells (some which were intersected by lines, some not).

Comment: The Split Features dataset must be polygons. Are you sure the tools can split lines with polygons?

Comment: Could it be a problem with your machine's capabilities? Is there ample space in the working directory?

Comment: @Jakub, yes it splits fine on smaller cell counts(and even most of the larger cells). The machine should be able to handle this; new desktop with quick CPU/lots of ram/lots of diskspace

Comment: Did you try running Repair geometry before running the split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another potential workflow:
1. Intersect the Roads with the polygons, outputting "lines". This will divide the roads along the polygons.
2. Use [the split by attribute tool](http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html) or something similar to divide the roads into separate files based on the FID field from the polygons.

I suspect this will be much faster than looping through the clip function.

Comment: Great suggestion, Patrick. All I need is the total length of the road per grid which I can then calculate within Python (or R! using `doBy`) as the intersected line takes on the attribute of the grid.

Comment: Or calculate it in Access. It's funny - I did this exact thing yesterday. Sorry I didn't think of it sooner!

Comment: It's still useful, and orders of magnitude quicker than my first approach.

Comment: +1 This is the method I would recommend, and a couple months back posted a workflow that I could follow in Google Docs (look at step 6): https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0ByyniRdjCwdiMmQ4ODlmZTYtYzk1MC00NmVlLWI5MDItZjA2NTM2MGExOGU2&hl=en_US where the Intersect tool is what does all the heavy lifting.

Comment: +1 for saving old workflows. I should start doing that...

Answer (score 1):

One way to work around this would be to loop in Python, selecting each grid cell, clipping the other layer using `Clip_analysis()`, and then selecting the next cell.

I have no idea how long this would take, but it shouldn't require any manual input, possibly saving you some time.

Comment: Patrick, how do I clip based on a selected cell? Do I need to export it first? I'm familiar with Python, just not familiar with how to do this.

Comment: Clip always only uses the selected features. So, if you use `SelectLayerByAttribute_management()` to loop through your grid cells, using an FID or something, you could easily run a `Clip_analysis` on each cell.

Comment: I noticed as I was testing that `Clip_analysis` seems very sensitive to the number of objects in the `in_features`, so if speed is important, you may want to break up your feature layers into a handful of separate areas.